# DAX LASTDATE Formula With Criteria

Tags: excel, dax

Please Help.

My table (TestTable) has the following columns - Individual / Date / Pct. Achieved.

I am trying to use the LASTDATE function to work out when an individual last achieved 90% or above.
My forumla thus far is as follows;

```
=CALCULATE(LASTDATE(TestTable[Date]),FILTER('TestTable',[Pct. Achieved]>0.895))
```

This works but only shows when the last individual achieved >90% and uses that date for everyone else. However, I would like it to look at each individual separately and return a date for when that individual last achieved >90%.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "**only shows when the last individual achieved >90%**".  Which visual are you  using this measure in? <br/> Measure work w.r.t to the selected data in the page. If you use this measure in a pivot-table, I think it should work as desired.

Comment: I have added the formula to my data model as a calculated column and will be using the measure in a pivot table. For example I have Individuals A - D. The last >90% achieved was by Individual B on the 16/03/2020. When I pivot the data and add Individual & Pct. Achieved as rows it comes up with 16/03/2020 for everyone (A-D). However, the last date Individual A achieved >90% was 01/03/2020 and C 15/02/2020. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Try adding another condition in the filter like so: "CALCULATE(LASTDATE(TestTable[Date]),FILTER('TestTable',[Pct. Achieved]>0.895 **&& [Individual] = FIRSTNONBLANK(TestTable[Individual],"")**))

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it split by individual, then you'll need to add the individual to your filter:

```
CALCULATE (
    LASTDATE ( TestTable[Date] ),
    FILTER (
        TestTable,
        TestTable[Pct. Achieved] > 0.895 &&
        TestTable[Individual] = EARLIER ( TestTable[Individual] )
    )
)
```

Note: `EARLIER` has nothing to do with dates but rather refers to the earlier row context (rather than the row context within `FILTER`).

Comment: Thank you very much.